# How to refresh total value every time whenever I add other value in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

```
var real_price = $('#price').text(); // getting values from total
var s1_price = $("input[name=s_sub_service]:checked").val(); // getting checked radio button value.
$('#price').text(parseInt(s1_price) + parseInt(string1)); // showing total value in price id.
```

Here I am adding different different value and give a total value. The problem is whenever I add new value into total and it gives me old value too and add into the total.

Comment: What's the value of `string1`

Comment: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/c64xfrpr/: you can edit as you want.

Comment: it is working fine but i have bith radio and checkbox, and i want to change their values.

Comment: Your js fiddle is working fine when i added value in total in gives correct value but when i decrease value in is not able to minus the value from total.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```js
$("input").on("change keyup", function(e) {
  var checkboxVal = parseInt($("input[type='radio']:checked").val(), 10);
  var price = parseInt($("#price").val(), 10);
  if (isNaN(price)) {
    price = 0;
  }
  var finalPrice = price + checkboxVal;
  $("#out").html(finalPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="5" checked>5
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="10">10
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="15">15
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="20">20
<br/>
<input type="text" id="price">
<div id="out">
</div>
```